# Shopify get theme content JSON response using API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

I am doing application for shopify using shopifyGraphQL storefront.

On the shopify website is using some theme. from the theme admin can sent banner and some advertisement message.

now i want to get those home page data on my mobile application (Data is set on the theme so question is how to get those data using APIs or any other way.)
using GraphQL API or any normal Rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Id done many R & D  i found that  themes are dome by the various shopify developers and they live those application/themes on the https://apps.shopify.com so every developer that done the custom work apart from the default shopify facility they store data in their custom database.

So, if theme developer it self provide some APIs then only you can get those changes otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use the Shopify Storefront Graphql API.

As I know you can't query liquid code but maybe you could try to fetch the contents of your webpage via the fetchAPI?

**Reference**:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront

https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/building-with-the-storefront-api/products-collections/getting-started

Comment: That i know and i already call data from storefront API, i am taking about get the get installed theme data

Comment: Ah, I understand. I didn't find any resources about that. I am not sure but I think you can't query liquid code directly but maybe you could use a normal fetch request to fetch the contents of your website?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a [section rendering API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/section-rendering) that you can utilize to get selected sections. This API will return HTML of selected sections in a string format, so you can convert it to fit in your application.

If you are using JS, you can use it like:

```
export const renderSection = async (sectionId, path = '/') => {
  const hostName = 'https://your-host.com';
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      hostName + path + `?sections=${sectionId}`
    );
    const result = await res.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

the returned JSON object would look like:

```
{
  [sectionId]: '<div>...</div>',
};
```